# Creating a timer in a Canvas- multithreading

Tags: android, eclipse, multithreading

This is my code, when the app started I saw only a black screen.
I wanted the app to add time counter, but I think that my multithreading has some problems.

```
        timeCounter.startcount();
        while(pressed!=true){
            if (!holder.getSurface().isValid()) 
                continue;
            Canvas c= holder.lockCanvas();
            c.drawBitmap(galaxy, 30, 0, null);
            c.drawBitmap(player, x-(player.getWidth()/2), y-(player.getHeight()/2), null);
            c.drawText(timeCounter.toString(), 30, 60, timerpaint);
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        }
    }
```

The timers class(Im not sure that this thread is OK):

```
public class TimeCounter
{
    private int smallestseconds=0;
    private int seconds=0;
    private int minute=0;
    public TimeCounter()
    {
        smallestseconds=0;
        seconds=0;
        minute=0;
    }
    public void startcount()
    {
        Thread t=new Thread();
        while(pressed!=true)
        {
            try{
                t.sleep(10);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                smallestseconds++;
                if(smallestseconds==100)
                {
                    smallestseconds=0;
                    seconds++;
                    if(seconds==60)
                    {
                    seconds=0;  
                    minute++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return(minute+":"+seconds+":"+smallestseconds);
    }
}
```

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to do? What errors are you getting? If you're trying to just get a counter since the app started you can use System.currentTimeMillis() at the startup, then subtract that from another call to System.currentTimeMillis() and format.

Comment: I want to count and show the time past since this activity started until its ends("pressed"==true).  If I will do it with your suggestion(if I got it right) it won't write every milisecond that past.

Comment: [SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html) will give you the number of milliseconds you've been in a thread. If you call this on the UI thread it'll give you the number of milliseconds your app has been running.